# Docker-Compose YML with ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API and SQL Server 2017

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core

I am new to Docker (v19.03.0) which I am using with Visual Studio 2019 (v16.2.0) and .NET Core 2.2, and I was hoping I could get some help with my `docker-compose.yml` file as want to create a microservice that consists of my Web API and SQL Server 2017.

At the moment, my Web API is pointing to a containerised Linux instance of SQL 2017, which is volume mounting my database from my `C:\DockerVolumes` drive.  This is working via IIS perfectly fine at the moment.

The next step was to containerise my Web Api which I did by right clicking my project in Visual Studio, and after running `docker ps -a` it seems to be running along side my SQL container.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    web:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            context: .
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest'
        ports:
            - '1433:1433'
        volumes:
            - 'C:\DockerVolumes:/var/opt/mssql/data'
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: 12345678
            ACCEPT_EULA: Y
```

This is where my `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` for my Web API reside:

[image: File Explorer Visual Studio]

Here is the `Dockerfile` for my Web Api:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SnowdonAPI_05/SnowdonAPI_05.csproj", "SnowdonAPI_05/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SnowdonAPI_05/SnowdonAPI_05.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SnowdonAPI_05"
RUN dotnet build "SnowdonAPI_05.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SnowdonAPI_05.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SnowdonAPI_05.dll"]
```

Before I do anything else I wanted to make sure I haven't missed anything (either steps or things in my `yml` file, obviously the only thing I can think of with regards to my Web Api is changing the connection string to `server=db;.....` once the services start.  Also, I am not sure if the port mapping are necessary for SQL?

Any help would be much appreciated, and if there is anymore information needed let me know.

Comment: This all looks ok to me. Re port mapping, it's needed to expose the port. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

Comment: Do you get any error while building by docker-compose?

Answer (score 1):

For your current docker-compose and dockerfile, the relative path for dockerfile is wrong.

For docker-compose, you specify the current docker-compose build path is `context: .`.

For dockerfile, your solution and dockerfile are in the same folder, but you build it with `COPY ["SnowdonAPI_05/SnowdonAPI_05.csproj", "SnowdonAPI_05/"]`, it will cause error since `SnowdonAPI_05/SnowdonAPI_05.csproj` will not be found.

There are two options for you:

1. Change all the source path in dockerfile to  relative to dockerfile path like changing `COPY ["SnowdonAPI_05/SnowdonAPI_05.csproj", "SnowdonAPI_05/"]` to `COPY ["SnowdonAPI_05.csproj", "SnowdonAPI_05/"]`
2. Move docker-compose to parent folder and change `dockerfile: Dockerfile` to `dockerfile: SnowdonAPI_05/Dockerfile`

Comment: Thanks, I think its easier, since Visual Studio automatically creates the `Dockerfile` to go with option `2`.  So, does `context: .` stay the same?  I'm a bit confused as it states in the docs that `context` is a path to the build, but we are stating the path as `dockerfile: SnowdonAPI_05/Dockerfile`

Comment: @user1574598 If you move docker-compose to parent folder, your docker `Dockerfile` will be in `SnowdonAPI_05/Dockerfile` according `context: . `

Comment: I've ran `docker-compose up` and it hung on this line: `Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.` then I hit CTRL + C and it said `gracefully` stopping.  It started with a warning after running the two services: `warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]` See my edited post for a screen grab.

Comment: @user1574598 It seems your docker build and run correctly, if you have any issue with your running project, I would recommend you open a new thread, and share us the detail error and code.